# ASP.NET MVC 5 Visual studito 2015 browser link 37, error script

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Why I met an error:
localhost:43996/__browserLink/requestData/4614286800f44c78bbfb618dfd443476?version=2

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image: Error]

It occurs when the first I click View in browser (Ctrl+ Shift+ W)
[image]

And if I 2nd press F5 or refresh page on browser then i don't see that error again.

Comment: Try disabling the browser link feature in visual studio before debugging your web app. As we cannot determine what it is trying to load maybe it's just a bug on the browser link.

Comment: i have tried to disable browser link feature and it don't show that error but, when i click my function ajax, it also be error.
Notice: when I press F5 on browser then errors do not happen again